# XQuery: How to add a comma after sequence except for the last element

Tags: xquery, xpath-2.0

I have the following xml:

```
<form>
<bibl>
    <biblScope>1</biblScope>
    <biblScope>a</biblScope>
</bibl>
<bibl>
    <biblScope>2</biblScope>
    <biblScope>b</biblScope>
</bibl>
<bibl>
    <biblScope>38</biblScope>
    <biblScope>c</biblScope>
</bibl>
</form>
```

Using this XQuery

```
for $bibl in form/bibl 
return
<div>
{
for $biblScope in $bibl/biblScope/text()
    return
    $biblScope
}
{if ($bibl[position()] ne $bibl[last()]) then ',' else '@'}
</div>
```

The `<biblScope>` contents are printed one after another. After each `bibl`element, I would like to add a separator (comma / ",") except for the last one, but with the code above, all I get is

```
<div>
1a
@
</div>
<div>
2b
@
</div>
<div>
38c
@
</div>
```

and this is definitely wrong, because what I would like to have is

```
<div>1a,</div>
<div>2b,</div>
<div>38c@</div>
```

(add a comma after every `bibl` element content; the last one is supposed to be followed by `@` instead of a comma.)

Having tried different things for some time now, I could need some help. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Your output and query don't fit together. Where are the `<div/>` elements, where the `<biblCope/>` ones?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow misconfigured the online XQuery tool, so that the ouput was wrong. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: please show an exact example of what the desired output should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `position()` and `last()` work on the current context, which is not set by flwor expressions. If you want to use similar semantics, use the `at $position` syntax to get a position counter, and define `$last` as the number of results:

```
let $last := count(form/bibl)
for $bibl at $position in form/bibl 
return
<div>
{
for $biblScope in $bibl/biblScope/text()
    return
    $biblScope
}
{if ($position ne $last) then ',' else '@'}
</div>
```

If you're able to use XQuery 3.0, the application operator `!` might be of use here. Replacing the unnecessary loops by axis steps and element constructors in those, you can rely on the positional predicates, as the context is set to to `<bibl/>` elements:

```
form/bibl ! <div>
{
  biblScope/text(),
  if (position() ne last()) then ',' else '@'
}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jens, for giving a working answer. However, as Michael Kay suggested, I replaced the second FLWOR (``for $biblScope in $bibl/biblScope/text() ...``) by ``$bibl/biblScope/text()``. I will definitely take a look at the application operator you mentioned, as it makes the code much easier to read. Thanks again for taking the time!

Comment: You should be able to use an axis step instead, but it seems at least BaseX and eXist DB have some issues in this regard. BaseX also received a bug report, I'll take care of the one for eXist DB as soon as I get around to it.

Answer (score 4):

First note that this:

```
for $biblScope in $bibl/biblScope/text()
    return
    $biblScope
```

can be replaced by this:

```
$bibl/biblScope/text()
```

(This bit of verbosity is a surprisingly common mistake. It suggests you're thinking procedurally - processing items one at a time, rather than processing sets.)

Then this:

```
<div>
{$bibl/biblScope/text()}
{if ($bibl[position()] ne $bibl[last()]) then ',' else '@'}
</div>
```

should be replaced by this:

```
<div>{string-join($bibl/biblScope, ',')}@</div>
```

Note that I've also got rid of the unnecessary (and arguably incorrect) use of `/text()`, which is another XQuery anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to correct my code (still have so much to learn)! Although I understand what happens in ``<div>{string-join($bibl/biblScope, ',')}@</div>``, the output is still not what I would like to have, as there is now a comma after each ``<biblScope>`` AND "@" after each ``<bibl>`` content. In fact I'd like to have a comma after each ``<bibl>`` except for the last one. Inserting ``@`` was originally meant for testing (for the last ``<bibl>`` under ``form``, show ``@`` instead of ``,``)...

Comment: It would make life a lot easier if you showed us your desired output.